# Adding a confirmation modal (Bootstrap) inside a Blade (Laravel) template loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm currently trying to make a nice confirmation screen when clicking in the delete button of the desired user inside a users table. My issue is I can't get to use a Bootstrap modal to delete the user as that deletes the last user if the modal isn't placed inside the loop, but if inside the loop it'll print as many modals as entries it finds.

My code is the following (Placing the modal outside the loop, where it should be!)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Usuario</td>
                            <td>Nombre</td>
                            <td>Apellido</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>Acceso</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($users as $key => $value)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $value->username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->role }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('usuarios/' . $value->id) }}">Mostrar</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-warning" href="{{ URL::to('usuarios/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Editar</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete-user-modal">Borrar</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".create-user-modal">Crear usuario</a><br />
                {{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade delete-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar usuario</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>¿Estás seguro que deseas elminar el usuario <strong>{{ Auth::User()->username }}</strong>?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                &nbsp;
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'usuarios/' . $value->id, 'class' => 'pull-right'))  }}
                    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Borrar', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

public function destroy($id)
{
    // buscar y eliminar usuario
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();

    // redirigir a usuarios con mensaje mensaje
    return Redirect::to('usuarios');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily ended up fixing it by adding the {{ $value->id }} to the modal CSS class', allowing me to only open the one that I have clicked inside the loop. The code goes as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete-user-modal{{ $value->id }}">Borrar</a>

<div class="modal fade delete-user-modal{{ $value->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar usuario</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>¿Estás seguro que deseas eliminar el usuario <strong>{{ $value->username }}</strong>?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            &nbsp;
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'usuarios/' . $value->id, 'class' => 'pull-right'))  }}
                {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                {{ Form::submit('Borrar', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```